# Google Maps not showing on release apk

Tags: android

Hello when I put the release apk of my google maps app on my phone it works great, but it does not work on other phones which is strange becausd i have the right api key and the right sha1 fingerprint of my keystore file??? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: please check my answer and see if it helps.I believe it's for the same reason mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to generate a separate key for your app which is going to be released.In this key you need to use the SHA1 of the signed apk.
Please check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810212/google-map-not-loading-on-normal-devices-but-loads-on-test-devicereal-device/28810369#28810369) link for detailed steps

For signing your app in android studio and obtaining new key,you can use [This](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) and [This](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Generating_a_Signed_Release_APK_File_in_Android_Studio).

Comment: Have you tried sending the apk to a friend ? have you tried to check version ?

Comment: Thanks but how can I do this in Android Studio?