# Google maps not loading in Signed APK in android

Tags: android, google-maps

We have implemented Google Maps API V2 and it works fine in development. When the APK is signed and published in Google Play the maps doesn't appears.It loads with a blank White screen with MyLocation button and Zooming controls button.
How to make display the maps on the play store version.
And also,we have generated the Key with keystore file

And also iahd checked with is stackoverflow question:Google map not loading on normal devices but loads on test device(real device) 
Still now the same problem exists for us

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: For signed apk, you will be needing to generate a new map key.

Comment: Did you add both release and debug SHA1 to your API key?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google map not loading on normal devices but loads on test device(real device)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810212/google-map-not-loading-on-normal-devices-but-loads-on-test-devicereal-device)

Comment: Check this link may helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983405/google-map-not-showing-when-make-signed-apk

Comment: I created a new key with the sha1 finger print obtained from when exporting the apk

Comment: Yes,I had added it still now the same problem only exits @shkschneider

Comment: Anything in the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

When you test your application during development, you obviously used you Eclipse/Android-Studio debug key. This means that the IDE (Eclipse or Android Studio or w/e) sign your application automatically to save you the trouble, in order to test it fast. They key used for this signing is different than the one for publishing applications on Google Play.

So, you need to follow the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Following the guide, you should be able to generate a "release" key to use with your published application (instead of the debug key that you have been using until now).